# Bootstrap modal protractor testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I have a problem with testing a bootstrap modal.

Scenario:

- click to a button to show modal
- the modal body contains a list of buttons
- when i click one of them doesn't perform the action

Protractor Code:

```
element(by.model('$root.project.modules.manufacturer.name')).click();
element.all(by.css('[ng-click="thisManuf(manufactur.name,manufactur.id);$hide(); "]')).get(0).click();
```

Error trace:

> UnknownError: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (584, 170). Other element would receive the click: ...

Help Please

Comment: You may need to wait after clicking to bring up the modal before clicking "in" the modal?  (Depending on how directly the modal is activated.)

Answer (score 0):

Find the buttons by [exact repeater](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.exactRepeater) instead:

```
var buttons = element.all(by.exactRepeater("manufactur in manufacturs"));
buttons.first().click();
```

Comment: the same error the problem is

                  Element is not clickable at point (234, 257)

the button may be disabled or something like that

Comment: @Hamdi could you share the HTML code of the target page, or at least the link to the website if it is public? Thanks.